# Convention for structuring python modules

Tags: python, module, structure, convention, pep

Is there a PEP or generally binding convention for structuring the content of python modules?
I currently structure them like

1. module-doctring
2. meta variables (__all__, __author__, __version__, ...)
3. includes
4. module methods
5. classes

Which looks like this (no module methods here):

```
"""
Generic clients

This package contains abstract, generic clients for foreign-API interaction.
Please see the client's documentation for advises for implementation. 
"""
__date__ = "16.07.2014"
__author__ = "My Name <me@company.com>"
__all__ = ['ImportClient',
           'ExportClient',
           'IEClient', 
           'CRUDClient']

from .abc import CustomerAwareConfigurableSlaveLog
from ..config import Config
import pyopenimmo as OpenImmo
from abc import abstractmethod

class ImportClient(CustomerAwareConfigurableSlaveLog):
    """
    Generic client that can import OpenImmo data
    """
    @abstractmethod
    def import_(self, openimmo):
        """
        Imports OpenImmo data from API
        """
        pass


class ExportClient(CustomerAwareConfigurableSlaveLog):
    """
    Generic client that can export OpenImmo data
    """
    @abstractmethod
    def export(self, openimmo): #@UnusedVariable
        """
        Exports OpenImmo data to API
        """
        return
<snip>
```

This seems quite feasible to me, but I want also others to find my code easy to understand.

Comment: That ordering matches what I'd expect... Part of it comes from necessity e.g. you have to import packages before you can use them. It's also 'traditional' for code files to have a header of some sort at the top of the file, which is common with other written work - books (a preface), magazines (summary from the editor) etc.

Comment: As long as it's readable and structured, it'll be easy to understand. Even more with comments. If you want a more detailed answer, ask to codereview.